# How to call an external keylistener class into the project text field?

Tags: java

I would like create a GUI in java. I want to create up a library to adding some listener or event and this class will be call to instance jTextField in another project when needed but it's not fired.

#1. Class listener

```
 public class jTEXTFIELDLISTENER implements KeyListener, FocusListener{

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "keytyped");
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    
    if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "keyPressed");
     }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "keyReleased");
}

@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
    
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "focusLost");
} 
}
```

#2. I build this Lib and call in new project.

```
 public void run() {
     new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
     NewJFrame f = new NewJFrame();
     f.start();
 }

  private void start() {
    text.addKeyListener(new jTEXTFIELDLISTENER());
}
```

Whatever, this code can't fire. Can anyone me to handle this issue?
I tried to research online for multiple links, but all of them are called listener inside the main frame but my way need to create up an external class.

Please, anyone suggest me.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You are calling `new NewJFrame()` twice, which means you have two instances of your `NewJFrame` class. You are calling `setVisible()` on one and `start()` on the other. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to create new object for NewJFrame() but it can not be call the class jTEXTFIELDLISTENER() directly.

Comment: If you want only one instance of `NewJFrame()` you want to work with then use the code `new NewJFrame()` only once.

Comment: My purpose just want to send an instance jTextField to this class jTEXTFIELDLISTENER() and return request event to GUI.

Comment: But how the listener will fire?

Comment: This class jTEXTFIELDLISTENER() will purpose to be called everywhere I need.

Comment: The problem is that you have **two** instances of `NewJFrame`. On one instance you are calling `setVisible()`, on the other you register the listeners. You have to work with only **one** instance of `NewJFrame`, so use only one `new NewJFrame()` code.

Comment: You're alright. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

@Progman
you're right.

To remove one instance of NewJFrame() was working for me.

```
      public void run() {
            NewJFrame f = new  NewJFrame();
            f.start();
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Thank you very much.